# remote debug chrome on iphone using windows

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-chrome

I know to debug mobile safari you'll need a mac, but is it possible to debug ios version of chrome on a windows machine (via a usb cable)? seems like a simple question, but for some reason I can't find anything on it using google. everything I find always seems to point to debugging mobile safari via mac or debugging mobile chrome for mac users.

FYI: I plan on getting the device, but I need to know if the aforementioned is possible before getting the iphone.

Comment: I've been wondering the same for years. Developing for iOS browsers has been really hard. I can't even get Safari to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714766/470749